# change bar color by interactivity of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm practicing the interactivity of matplotlib now, I want to change color by the value I press on the picture. But after I execute my codes, nothing happened, I have tested it using print to see if it successfully interact or not, and it did. It just doesn't change color.
Here are a part of my codes.

```
def onclick(event):
   yclick=event.ydata
   paint=probability_cal(yclick, interval)
   color=np.array(paint)
   color1=cm.coolwarm(color)
   for i in range(len(df)):
       bars[i].set_color(color1[i])

cid=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

'bars' is the bar chart I created beforehand.
and 'color1' is an np.array looks like [0.9396231304298562,1.0,1.0,1.0]

Comment: Once the graph is drawn is does not redraw unless asked. Your code changes the property but does not redraw the graph.  Take a look at matplotlib.animation, specifically the blit aspect.  Note if you are using Jupyter you need a different method.  I would write an example but I don't have time right now.

Comment: I add fig.canvas.draw() and it worked, but I'm still curious, some of the example I found online didn't need to use this, and some of them did, trying to figure out what's the concept between all this.